# How to write Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi i am using the following line of code in mvc application working fine.

> Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]

How to get ipaddress in asp.net core. I wrote the following code in asp.net core but it always returns null.

```js
 protected string GetClientIPAddress()
        {
#if DEBUG
            return _configuration.GetSection("IPAddress")?.Value;
#else
            string ipAddress = string.Empty;
            if (Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
            {
                ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            }
            return ipAddress;
#endif
        }
```

Comment: what issue you are facing when you use `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` in asp.net core? Did you try using `Request.Headers["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` ?

Comment: Hi Chetan, Request.Headers also returns null value

Answer (score 0):

See [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer) and use the [Forwarded Headers Middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/) that updates RemoteIpAddress using the X-Forwarded-For header value.